# Failed to initialize NVML: Unknown Error

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, cuda

When i run `nvcc --version` on my terminal I get:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2015 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Aug_11_14:27:32_CDT_2015
Cuda compilation tools, release 7.5, V7.5.17
```

But when I write nvidia-smi it gives me the following error:

```
Failed to initialize NVML: Unknown Error
```

Comment: Hey, sorry. I just changed my query